# iOS RestKit Authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I am very new to iOS development. This is my first application and I am in big trouble. I do not know how to start with RestKit. I am trying to implement RestKit authentication in my iOS App since past 3 weeks. I looked around for many solutions but everyone has given a different approach, so could not able to extract which will be useful for me.

I have web services ready which I already use in my Android application. Now I want to make use of same web services for iOS.

So for authentication, I have a **login service** which takes **username and password** as parameters. It **returns a boolean** value (not JSON or XML, but simply true or false).
So I did not found any solution on how to handle boolean kind of response from web server.

If anybody can help me to sort out this problem. If anyone has implemented similar kind of behavior then please help me on how to start with rest kit. i.e how to send request and how to access response send by the server.

I have provided piece of code which I tried to implement.

```
RKURL * baseUrl = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"https://webserver.org/login"];

RKObjectManager * objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseUrl];

objectManager.client.username = txtUserName.text;
objectManager.client.password = txtPassword.text;
objectManager.client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;
objectManager.client.disableCertificateValidation = YES;

[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", [baseUrl      resourcePath], nil] delegate:self];
```

Thanks in advance,
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of web service is this? It returns simply a word (true or false)? How will you handle errors with this? The problem is not Restkit, it is your web service. Are you in control of your web server response?

Comment: thanks for your reply..but I am using same web service in my Android application. It works well. So what should my web service return, either JSON or XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your backend does not return an object (xml or json) there's no point to use  `RKObjectManager`. Instead, try sending the request directly with `RKClient`'s `get:queryParameters:delegate:` selector which gives you lower level API compared to `RKObjectManager`.

Also, you said your WS takes username and password as input - if you set username and password properties on `RKClient` the credentials will be used for basic HTTP Auth. the `queryParameters` dictionary should hold any input parameters for your web services.

*Example:*

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] get:myResource queryParameters:params delegate:self];
```

be sure to implement the delegate

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
```

for more detail refer to the [documentation](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKClient.html#task_Sending%20Asynchronous%20Requests).

Comment: thank you for your reply..
After reading comment of Paul de Lange, I just want to confirm that is it possible to handle boolean kind of response through RKClient.
And if you have any sample code or any link which I can refer..
that will be very much appreciated...